# Se a imagem for grande na vertical ficar com height:100%, se for grande na horizontal, ficar com width:100%?

Tags: html, css

Estou com uma dúvida, como faço para poder inserir imagens com tamanhos diferentes dentro de uma div, sendo que, se a imagem for muito grande verticalmente, ela fique com **height:100%**, e caso for muito grande horizontalmente com **width:100%**?

Uma imagem como exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sem javascript? Não sei se é possível ein...

Answer (score 9):

Utilize uma combinação de imagens de fundo e configurações de comportamento via CSS.

Explicação:

- `background-size:contain` forçará a imagem de fundo a ser contida dentro do elemento;
- `background-repeat:no-repeat` fará a imagem aparecer apenas uma vez;
- `background-position: center` centralizará a imagem nos dois eixos, independente de tamanho ou largura.

```css
.container {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
  border:1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div class='container' style='background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Wide_view_over_S%C3%B8rfjorden_from_the_coast_of_Sveingard,_2012_June.jpg)'>
  
</div>
<div class='container' style='background-image:url(http://wvs.topleftpixel.com/photos/scotia_plaza_tall_stitched.jpg)'>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se estás a tentar fazer isso utilizando a tag `<img>`, podes fazer isso **não especificando** uma `altura` ou `largura` para a imagem, mas sim definindo os seguintes valores:

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

E para centralizar a imagem ao centro:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

> Existem outras formas de centralizar elementos ao centro, mas neste caso foi esta a maneira que utilizei.

Tudo junto ficará algo como neste exemplo abaixo do CodeSnippet:
(Tens aqui também um <kbd>[EXEMPLO NO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2m56au4g/)</kbd> se preferires)

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.caixa {
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #C8ECFF;
    border:2px solid #717171;
    margin-bottom:15px;

    /* Centralizando imagens */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="caixa">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>

<div class="caixa">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixe a largura e altura máxima:

```
<img src="suaimagem.jpg" style="max_width:123px; max-height=123px"></img>
```

Answer (score -1):

No seu css defina o style da seguinte maneira:

```
<style>
img{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Amigo o `auto´ ele apenas irá pegar o próprio tamanho da imagem upada. Exemplo ela é de 325px450 com auto ela irá ficar com exatamente este mesmo valor, o caso dele é o seguinte, a imagem é 400x100 ele quer que a imagem fique por exemplo 100%x40%.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues Com o 'auto' a imagem se adequará de acordo com o tamanho do elemento em que ela estiver. E é o que ele quer, ajustar a imagem de acordo com a div. Aí basta ver onde encaixa melhor. Se for maior verticalmente: 'height:auto', se for maior horizontalmente: 'width:auto'

Answer (score -1):

Para resolver seu problema você deve pegar pelo Javascript o tamanho da imagem e fazer uma comparação entre o width e o heigth. No nosso exemplo, utilizaremos a tag

1º Pegamos o tamanho pelo jQuerey:

```
Largura = $('img#foto').width();
Altura = $('img#foto').height();
```

2° Fazer comparação para saber qual é maior:

```
if(largura > altura){
   $('foto').css("width","100%");
}else{
   $('foto').css("height","100%");
}
```

Provavelmente isto resolverá seu problema.